# Unable to Get mongo-go driver using the command "go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to get mongodb go driver for my sample appliation. I am following the instructions mentioned in the page https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver. When I execute the `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` I am getting this error on my virtual box ubunto 18.04 VM:

```
Error from ubunto18.04 VM
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
# cd .; git clone -- https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver.git /root/sun/ws/golang/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
Cloning into '/root/sun/ws/golang/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver'...
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 3229733: inflate returned -5
fatal: index-pack failed
package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo: exit status 128
```

Comment: worked for me on my mac just now. Can you retry and check if you can checkout any other repository from github?

Comment: You have some kind of a system issue with zilb it seems.

Comment: Are you able to install other go modules successfully?

Comment: The error code seems to indicate a buffer error in zlib. My bet is on a problem in the network setup.